# Changes to registry via batch/.reg file not persisting after restart Windows 10

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry, windows-10

I'm making a script to change the target paths for a few user folders.

Here is my .reg file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders]
"Personal"="C:\\Users\\%username%\\Google Drive\\Documents\\"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders]
"Desktop"="C:\\Users\\%username%\\Google Drive\\Desktop\\"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders]
"Downloads"="C:\\Users\\%username%\\Google Drive\\Downloads\\"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders]
"My Pictures"="C:\\Users\\%username%\\Google Drive\\Pictures\\"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders]
"Favorites"="C:\\Users\\%username%\\Google Drive\\Favorites\\"
```

It changes the registry setting perfectly. However, I restart the box and it's still going to default `%userprofile%\documents`. If I click the property tab on the folder and when I check the registry it is still changed from my script. If I do it manually it works. However, I'm scripting it to run it on 50 machines. I have done this before in XP without any issue. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

I also tried changing it in shell folders as well to no avail. I ran an app called *whatchanged* to capture the reg setting that are being modified when I change the target manually, but it captured 70 changes! I've tried running it as administrator, creating a folder in root C:\ with permissions for everyone but to no avail.

I also tried the syntax like this:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders] "Favorites"="C:\\Users\\%username%\\Google Drive\\Favorites\\"
```

Comment: I posted to a few power user forums on Spiceworks and other forums, read the articles on the subject through a search even though I've done this simple task before in XP way be I came here. My question got reworded by an admin, the issue is not with Windows retaining the change at all, its with the script making the change work in the first place. my script changes the reg value appropriately however the folders do not direct.

Comment: I've tried the path with %USERPROFILE% and tried making the change in both places shell and user shell. I reloaded two PC's with different Windows 10 builds, my script doesn't work. It's got to be something simple I'm missing

Comment: I used the tool 'Whatchanged' to monitor the registry setting that where changed when the manual process was done. That was the first step I did..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used syntax implies `REG_SZ` data type:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders]
"Personal"="%USERPROFILE%\\Documents"
```

**You need REG_EXPAND_SZ data type**; it should be as follows for above example:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders]
"Personal"=hex(2):25,00,55,00,53,00,45,00,52,00,50,00,52,00,4f,00,46,00,49,00,\
  4c,00,45,00,25,00,5c,00,44,00,6f,00,63,00,75,00,6d,00,65,00,6e,00,74,00,73,\
  00,00,00
```

I'd use [REG.exe](http://ss64.com/nt/reg.html) in a batch-file script, something like

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
set "_KeyName=HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders"
reg add "%_KeyName%"  /v Personal /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "%%USERPROFILE%%\Documents" /f
```